# Cannot locate rosdep definition, error on micro-ROS

Tags: ros2, microcontroller, micro-ros

I'm trying to set up micro-ROS on Ubuntu 20.04 using this [website](https://micro.ros.org/docs/tutorials/core/first_application_rtos/freertos/), and connect ESP32 to ROS 2. However, when executing the command `ros2 run micro_ros_setup create_firmware_ws.sh freertos esp32`, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
rclc_parameter: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [osrf_testing_tools_cpp]
rmw: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [osrf_testing_tools_cpp]
rmw_implementation: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [rcpputils]
rosidl_typesupport_c: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [mimick_vendor]
rosidl_default_runtime: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [rosidl_typesupport_introspection_cpp]
rcl_logging_noop: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [launch_testing]
rosidl_typesupport_microxrcedds_c_tests: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [rosidl_typesupport_introspection_c]
tracetools_launch: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [launch_ros]
rcutils: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [osrf_testing_tools_cpp]
rcl_action: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [osrf_testing_tools_cpp]
libyaml_vendor: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [rcpputils]
rcl_lifecycle: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [osrf_testing_tools_cpp]
tracetools_test: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [launch_ros]
test_rmw_implementation: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [rmw_dds_common]
rclc_lifecycle: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [osrf_testing_tools_cpp]
rosidl_typesupport_cpp: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [rcpputils]
rcl: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [rcpputils]
ros2trace: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [ros2cli]
rclc: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [osrf_testing_tools_cpp]
```

Is there any solution?

Incidentally, I implemented the following solution suggested by ChatGPT, but it didn't improve the situation.

- Update ROS 2 dependencies. `rosdep update`
- Install System Packages, which ROS2 packages or stacks depend on. `rosdep install --from-paths /path/to/your/ros2/workspace --ignore-src --rosdistro <your_ros_distro>`
- Rebuild the ROS 2 workspace. `colcon build`

Comment: Hi Leonardo. What ros distro are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mention that you are using `Ubuntu 20.04`, you can not use the tutorial. It is written for `Ubuntu 22.04`  ([https://micro.ros.org/docs/tutorials/core/first_application_rtos/freertos/#:~:text=Hawksbill%20on%20your-,Ubuntu%2022.04,-LTS%20computer.%20To](https://micro.ros.org/docs/tutorials/core/first_application_rtos/freertos/#:%7E:text=Hawksbill%20on%20your-,Ubuntu%2022.04,-LTS%20computer.%20To))

I assume you are trying to use **galactic**, which is not supported any more (https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Releases.html)

Comment: After I changed from ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04, the error has been resolved. Thank you!